# Does java hdfs client need to have core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml for connection?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I downloaded files from Hadoop server with HttpClient.

But other people said it's not good for security because it doesn't need to input user ID. So I have to change it to webhdfs or hdfs.

I have to connect with Hadoop and it's not mine.

So I don't know all of its configurations.

They told me the only username, some IP addresses, and ports.

But hdfs client in java program needs many configurations.

Does hdfs client need core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml for its configuration?

or do I have some other way to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to communicate with HDFS properly a client needs to know configuration parameters. And this is what those two files are all about and client needs configs from both files. As it stated [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/explaining-hadoop-configuration/):

> The core-site.xml file informs Hadoop daemon where NameNode runs in
>   the cluster. It contains the configuration settings for Hadoop Core
>   such as I/O settings that are common to HDFS and MapReduce.
>
> The hdfs-site.xml file contains the configuration settings for HDFS
>   daemons; the NameNode, the Secondary NameNode, and the DataNodes.

But in Java code, all configs (no matter from which file) are being carried by
`org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`. So, you can place everything in one Configuration object.

Hope this answers your question.